# Microsoft Visual Studio Load Test VS JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Can anyone please compare all the features of **MS-Visual Studio Load Test tool** and **JMeter tool**?

Here I already got few comparions with both,

1. Price

   - JMeter: free and open source
   - MSVS: Test Professional costs around $2000 per developer.
2. OS supported

   - JMeter: any
   - MSVS: Windows only
3. Protocols supported

   - JMeter: HTTP, FTP, JDBC, SOAP, TCP, JMS, SMTP, POP3, IMSP
   - MSVS: HTTP

But I need a comparison rather than this, Also I need to prove **JMeter** is worthy and better than **MS-VisualStudio Load Test**.

Comment: You are asking for tutorial

Comment: @user7294900  No, Iam not asking for tutorial, I just need a detail comparison on both of the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason of choosing JMeter is that [JMeter is being actively developed and supported](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/commits/trunk) and [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) is the last version to support [Coded UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2017) and [Load Testing features](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/microsoft-recommends-jmeter-and-blazemeter-as-preferred-load-testing-tools), they will be removed from the next releases.

So if you are looking for a load testing tool which will live at least several years - go for JMeter.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

You're being disingenuous on the protocols supported.  MSVSLT supports any protocol supported in Visual Studio, which includes all standard protocols for client server, web, even raw sockets mode.

Both are developer tools built for use by Developers.

It is true that Microsoft is abandoning the performance testing market with their tools.   This should be eye opening on how Microsoft views the importance of performance testing in their developer community.

Price is the absolutely last criteria you should be looking at for a delivery item on performance testing.  Why?  Because you can get a lot of cheap tools/free tools which may not exercise your interface, may not support your monitoring needs, will not support your analysis and reporting needs, and are flat out unusable on your reference platform and by your intended user population.

Start with your analysis and reporting.  This is where the value is added.  Running the load test is simply a controlled model for the production of timing records and resource measurements   This will provide a subset of tools that meet your business mission goals.

Next, look at your environment, for a list of tools which will collect resource measurements while your test is running.

Once you have a subset of tools that meet your business mission needs and your technical environment needs, then take a very keen look at your intended user population.   You may have the most effective tool on the planet, but if your team isn't capable of delivering high value, then you as well be deploying the least effective tool.  Your return on effort will be about the same.

Lastly, look at license model.  If you have no authority to authorize based upon price, then you should also lack the authority to reject based upon price.  Pass or reject on technical and mission capabilities.